# Unambiguous binary encoding scheme for the alphabet

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, binary, information-theory

An old [British Informatics Olympiad question](http://www.olympiad.org.uk/papers/2004/bio/q3.html) (3c) asks what the smallest unambiguous encoding scheme for the alphabet (using only two symbols - hence binary) is. As far as I can see, the answer is 130 - 5 bits are required to store each letter, as 2^4 < 26. The alphabet has 26 characters, so the encoding scheme is 5*26 bits long. However, the mark scheme states that 124 bits can be used. What is the encoding scheme that is that long?

Answer (score 2):

I think this works:

```
a - 0010
b - 0011
c - 0100
d - 0101
e - 0110
f - 0111
g - 10000
h - 10001
i - 10010
j - 10011
k - 10100
l - 10101
m - 10110
n - 10111
o - 11000
p - 11001
q - 11010
r - 11011
s - 11100
t - 11101
u - 11110
v - 11111
w - 00000
x - 00001
y - 00010
z - 00011
```

It is unambiguous. If a symbol starts with two or fewer zeros, it is of length 4. If it starts with a 1, it is length 5. If it starts with `000` then it is also length 5.

I got the idea by starting with a through h being length 4, using 0 as the first symbol. However, a scheme like that is short two symbols (if length is predicated entirely by the first symbol), so I looked for a way to reduce the number of four symbol codes by two... and noticed that `0000` and `0001` were the only two that had a triple`0`. Two bits give you four characters and the rest is an unambiguous encoding scheme :)

6 * 4 + 20 * 5 = 124

or alternatively

4 + 16 + 6 = 26

Comment: Good answer. In general if there are N letters in an alphabet the number of bits in the best unambiguous encoding is given by the "binary entropy function": http://oeis.org/A003314

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to not use a fixed-length encoding (as you have pointed out, ld(26) is somewhere between 4 and 5, thus we have unused blocks in a 5-bit encoding scheme), but vary the length of our data words so we get an optimized number of bits for each leter.

When creating a table of the 32 combinations, we can assign the letters A-Z to each value, with A starting at 00000, B = 00001 and so on. Z will be 11001 – the rest (11010…11111) will be unused.

Now it gets a bit trickier. We have six combinations at the end which are not used, but we cannot simply drop them, as there is no such thing as "half a bit of information". Therefore, we need to distribute six combinations so that we can drop the last bit of each of them. Example:

10100 = U, 10101 = V

becomes

10100 = U, 10110 = V

The other combinations are moved accordingly so the last bit of each of the last six letters is a "0". Then this bit can be dropped, so we end with these letters:

00000 = A, 00001 = B, …, 10011 = T, 1010 = U, 1011 = V, 1100 = W, 1101 = X, 1110 = Y, Z = 1111

**Important:** While this scheme is prefix-free (i.e. no combination is the start of another, longer combination) and thus unambiguous, it is not self-synchronizing, so we cannot just sneak into a stream of encoded characters and definitely get a correct output. This would require having a synchronization "character" that is not contained in any other letter - but that is not possible as this is a no-redundancy scheme.

Comment: Preferring this answer, because it describes the idea behind all this in greater detail. Also, I'd like to add that the approach is to make, at any point, a 0 as likely as a 1 (by doing one's best to "equalize" probabilities for both). As information theory shows, a discrete source of symbols (here: bits) has maximum average information per bit (i.e. entropy) if the probabilities of all produced symbols are equal (50% in this case).